Inclusion in polyhedron
Suppose I have a convex polyhedron, $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, represented by its extreme points $\{y^1,...,y^K\}$. Suppose further, that the polyhedron $P$ is unbounded to the north east: ${P}={P}\oplus\mathbb{R}^2_\geq$, where $\mathbb{R}^2_\geq=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2: y_1,y_2\geq 0\}$. I want to test if a point, say $z$, is included in ${P}$. It can be assumed that the extreme points are sorted such that $y^i_1<y^{i+1}_1$ and $y^i_2>y^{i+1}_2$.
My question is, whether it is sufficient that I only check whether the point $z$ lies above the line connecting the two points $y^i$ and $y^{i+1}$ with $y^i_1\leq z_1\leq y^{i+1}_1$? Obviously, if $z_1<y^1_1$ or if $z_2< y^K_2$, then $z\not\in P$.
If have included an illustration of the idea below. Here $z^2$ is not in $P$ as it lies below the line connecting $y^1$ and $y^2$. The point $z^1$ is in $P$, as it lies above the line connecting $y^3$ and $y^4$.

Hint: The verticals from each $y^i$ partition $P$.

@JMP So, if I understand you correctly, what you are saying is, that $P$ is partitioned into, in this case, four pieces, defined by the part above the lines $(y^1,y^2),...$ and hence, if $z$ is in $P$ it must be in exactly one of these. Also, $z$ cannot be in the pieces when its first coordinate is not between the points defining the piece. Hence, we should only check the piece defined by $(y^i,y^{i+1})$ where $y_1^i\leq z\leq y^{i+1}_1$.

Yes. It works for any monotonic sequence of a particular coordinate, here convex is monotonic in both $x$ and $y$.

Given a pair of consecutive vertices $y^k$, $y^{k+1}$, consider the function:
$$
f(z_1,z_2)=(z_2-y_2^k)(y_1^{k+1}-y_1^k)-(z_1-y_1^k)(y_2^{k+1}-y_2^k).
$$
This vanishes if $z$ lies on line $y^ky^{k+1}$ and is positive if $z$ is "north-east" of that line (you can check that $f>0$ for $z_1\to+\infty$ or $z_2\to+\infty$).
Hence $z$ lies (strictly) inside the polygon if $f>0$ for all pairs of consecutive vertices and in addition if $z_1>y_1^1$, $z_2>y^K_2$.
